# Magnolia CMS 5.5 Full Text Search

Tags: search, content-management-system, jackrabbit, magnolia

So I have a Magnolia CMS running with Pages that have Areas and Components with rich-text-fields and more. As I understood I can use templating functions

like: `searchfn.searchContent('website', queryStr, '/', "")`

to search for content. While debugging that I have no search results I found out that the query selects the term "rep:excerpt()". (see SearchTemplatingFunctions.java)

Can somebody explain where this excerpt comes from (autogenerated?) and perhaps give me a hint why I don't get any results..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rep:excerpt()` function will invoke configured excerpt provider from JR repo. By default (check your `WEB-INF/config/repo-config/jackrabbit***.xml`) it should be `info.magnolia.jackrabbit.lucene.SearchHTMLExcerpt`.

It's mainly to make sure search results are properly formatted when showing excerpts from documents found in search (should such contain html).

There should be no effect on whether or not you find any results.